# Column formatting from Fusion Tables NOT carrying over into map statement

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps-api-3, google-fusion-tables

I imported a kml file into fusion tables and have been trying to modify it into a particular product standard. Particularly, I need to re-adjust the floating point numbers into integers.

I already tried manually resetting the numbers that were not meant to be seen as floats in the fusion table (by adjusting the column settings). However in my 'infowindow' call statement they still remain as floats (for an example go here, BUT this is not my most up-to-date code....the below html file is....:http://www.solar.pioneervalleydata.org/html/map.html).

Can number formatting in fusion tables carry over in a map document? Is there an html approach I can take in my  statements to fix this (or is re-writting an array in my initialize function my only choice....which sounds like a pretty slow hack to me)...

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  google.maps.event.addListener(layer, 'click', function(e) {
    var contentString = [
             '<div class="tabs">',
         '<ul>',
     '<li><a href="#tab-1"><span>ROOF/PANEL AREA</span></a></li>' +
     '<li><a href="#tab-2"><span>ENERGY TOTALS</span></a></li>',
     '<ul>',
     '<div id="tab-1">',
     '<div class="contents" style="display:block">' + 
     '<p>' + '<br>' + '<br>' + 'Total Roof Area (sqft) :' +              
             '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + e.row['TOTAL_ROOF'].value + '</p>',
    '<p>' + 'Potential Roof Area (sqft) :' + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + 
             e.row['POTENTIAL_'].value + '</p>',
        '<p>' + 'Pitched or Flat Roof (?) :' + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + 
            e.row['PITCHED_OR'].value + '</p>',
    '<p>' + 'Number of Panels for available Roof Area :' + 
            '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + e.row['NUMBER_OF_'].value + '</p>',
    '</div>',
    '</div>',
    '<div id="tab-2">',
    '<div class="contents" style="display:block">' + 
    '<p>' + '<br>' + '<br>' + 'Watts generated (# of Panels * 250kw) :' + 
            '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + e.row['WATTS'].value + '</p>',
    '<p>' + 'Annual KWH inc. est. daylight/cloud conditions (Watts generated / 
           1.18125) :' + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + e.row['KWH_PER_YR'].value + '</p>',
    '<p>' + 'Value of Electricity PER Year (Annual KWH * .118) :' +     
           '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + e.row['ANNUAL_DOL'].value + '</p>',
    '<p>' + 'Value of Electricity PER Month (Electricity PER Year / 12) :' 
           + '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;' + e.row['MONTHLY_DO'].value + '</p>',
    '</div>',
    '</div>'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would keep the data in Fusion Tables. If I understand you correctly the data is not wrong, you just want to *display* it differently.

If this is the case, you can adjust the formatting of the InfoWindow. Just use JavaScript to change the display of the values. You can choose between several options to convert floats to integers:

- [`Math.floor()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/floor)
- [`Math.ceil()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil)
- [`Math.round()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round)

Example:

```
  '<p>' + 'Potential Roof Area (sqft) :' + Math.round(e.row['POTENTIAL_'].value) + '</p>'
```

Comment: Okay. Good call. I guess I was hoping the fusion tables side would be more flexible then it is.